# ASP.NET MVC - Razor: Fails to get styles on IIS Express

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, razor

Styles wont load when launching my web project via IIS Express (same on deploy). Only if I use local IIS the styles will display correctly.

Way I reference styles at layout:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/catalog/view/theme/lexus_powergame/stylesheet/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Browser gives this error: Failed to load resource: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED http://localhost/Content/catalog/view/theme/lexus_powergame/stylesheet/bootstrap.css`

Comment: Assuming you're using MVC4 or newer, you don't need @Url.Content(). localhost by itself won't work either, since IIS Express uses a format like localhost:12345 - how have you configured the project?

Comment: just default configuration by creating new project using Visual Studio

Comment: What do you see in PROJECT -> [your-project-name] Properties -> Web -> Servers?

Comment: IIS Express, Project url: http://localhost:5761/, Override application root (unchecked)

Comment: What happens if you replace your path with either `"~/Content/catalog/view/theme/lexus_powergame/stylesheet/bootstrap.css"` or `"/Content/catalog/view/theme/lexus_powergame/stylesheet/bootstrap.css"`? Also, if you've installed full IIS on your dev machine, you probably want to stop that service before starting IIS Express - I don't think they play well together.

Comment: Still same result -> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found that I got messed up 2 references before and all other refs was than pointing to localhost instead of valid location. :)